# Find rows where the majority of the columns are null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**The database:**

I have 2 tables. `Table1` has 50 fields and 25 of these are all named something like `SomeValue1`, `SomeValue2` ... `SomeValue25`. `Table2` is similar, except it ranges from `SomeOtherValue1` to `SomeOtherValue30`.

1) For both of these tables, these 'numbered' columns allow `null`.

2) For both of these tables, these 'numbered' columns should only allow a value if all previous columns before it are not `null`. So you should only be able to enter a value into `SomeValue3` if both `SomeValue1` and `SomeValue2` are not `null`.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to find all records from both tables where a given record has more than n fields that are not `null`.

Unfortunately, I can't trust the integrity of the data. I simply can't do `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SomeValueN IS NOT NULL` because I can't guarantee that rule #2 above was enforced.

**The question:**

Is there a way I can do something like `SELECT MyPrimaryKey FROM Table WHERE COUNT([all_columns with null values]) > n` without manually typing out every column name?

Comment: You could use list_Agg on the system table to combine all the columns so you don't have to type them :P  Alternatively you could concat all the columns < n together if null then you know a column is null that shouldn't be. if the result is not null then you know all preceding values are filled in.

Comment: Or combine `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE SomeValueN IS NOT NULL` with `and concat(somevalue1,somevalue2,somevalue3...) is not null`

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic unpivot using `cross apply(values ())` and aggregate and include `having count()...`

Test setup is a table with 25 nullable columns that start with `SomeValue`:

```
create table t (id int not null identity(1,1) , SomeValue1 int null , SomeValue2 int null , SomeValue3 int null , SomeValue4 int null , SomeValue5 int null , SomeValue6 int null , SomeValue7 int null , SomeValue8 int null , SomeValue9 int null , SomeValue10 int null , SomeValue11 int null , SomeValue12 int null , SomeValue13 int null , SomeValue14 int null , SomeValue15 int null , SomeValue16 int null , SomeValue17 int null , SomeValue18 int null , SomeValue19 int null , SomeValue20 int null , SomeValue21 int null , SomeValue22 int null , SomeValue23 int null , SomeValue24 int null , SomeValue25 int null ) 
insert into t values 
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
,(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, null)
,(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, null, null)
,(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, null, null, null)
,(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, null, null, null, null)
,(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, null, null, null, null, null)
,(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(22, 22, 22, 22, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(23, 23, 23, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(24, 24, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
,(25, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null)
```

Query:

```
declare @cols as nvarchar(max);
declare @sql as nvarchar(max);

set @cols = stuff((
   select ',(''' + C.name + ''','+ quotename(C.name) +')'
   from sys.columns c
   where c.object_id = object_id('dbo.t') /* <-- table name */
     and c.name like 'SomeValue%' /* <-- column name starts with */
   order by c.column_id
   for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'');

set @sql = '
select t.id --, u.column_name, u.column_value
from t
cross apply (
  values '+@cols+') u (column_name,column_value)
group by t.id
having count(u.column_value) > 10;' /* <-- how many not null */

select @sql as CodeGenerated;
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UKFM26061

Code Generated:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             CodeGenerated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |  |
|     select t.id --, u.column_name, u.column_value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |  |
|     from t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |  |
|     cross apply (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |  |
|       values ('SomeValue1',[SomeValue1]),('SomeValue2',[SomeValue2]),('SomeValue3',[SomeValue3]),('SomeValue4',[SomeValue4]),('SomeValue5',[SomeValue5]),('SomeValue6',[SomeValue6]),('SomeValue7',[SomeValue7]),('SomeValue8',[SomeValue8]),('SomeValue9',[SomeValue9]),('SomeValue10',[SomeValue10]),('SomeValue11',[SomeValue11]),('SomeValue12',[SomeValue12]),('SomeValue13',[SomeValue13]),('SomeValue14',[SomeValue14]),('SomeValue15',[SomeValue15]),('SomeValue16',[SomeValue16]),('SomeValue17',[SomeValue17]),('SomeValue18',[SomeValue18]),('SomeValue19',[SomeValue19]),('SomeValue20',[SomeValue20]),('SomeValue21',[SomeValue21]),('SomeValue22',[SomeValue22]),('SomeValue23',[SomeValue23]),('SomeValue24',[SomeValue24]),('SomeValue25',[SomeValue25])) u (column_name,column_value) |  |
|     group by t.id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |  |
|     having count(u.column_value) > 10;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Query Execution returns:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
|  9 |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
+----+
```